# Business models based on Torah

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, money, commentaries, business

Are there any good writings/books/halacha/teachings on how to integrate values (or certain commandments) of the Torah into a Business?

A friend of mine talked about the way he integrated his own belief with the way they work in there organization, which popped this question in my head and whether or not things like this are documentated in some form.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15193/halachic-sources-on-business-ethics-in-a-globalized-industry

Answer (score 2):

Feldheim has [some good books on business and ethics](http://www.feldheim.com/halacha/jewish-business-ethics.html) that might be of your interest. Also there is this sefer dealing with halachic business issues: [Business Halachah: A Practical Halachic Guide to Modern Business](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1422605477) by  Ari Marburger (Mesorah Publications).